# DynamicJasper: use array or list as datasource without objects

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

I'm using `DynamicJasper` to build reports but the only problem I face here is that you need to pass a collection of objects as datasource.
But in my case I need to pass a dynamic columns and data, example:
check this link http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/getting-started/:
under "**Creating a simple Report**" section they pass a list of `Product` as datasource :

```
FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
DynamicReport dr = drb.addColumn("State", "state", String.class.getName(),30)
.addColumn("Branch", "branch", String.class.getName(),30)
.addColumn("Product Line", "productLine", String.class.getName(),50)
.addColumn("Item", "item", String.class.getName(),50)
.addColumn("Item Code", "id", Long.class.getName(),30,true)
.addColumn("Quantity", "quantity", Long.class.getName(),60,true)
.addColumn("Amount", "amount", Float.class.getName(),70,true)
.addGroups(2)
.setTitle("November 2006 sales report")
.setSubtitle("This report was generated at " + new Date())
.setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true)
.setUseFullPageWidth(true)
.build();

JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(TestRepositoryProducts.getDummyCollection());// here they give list of Products
JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), ds);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
```

In this example they used list of `Product` entity where this entity has properties like `state`, `branch`, etc .. so it can match the given columns.

But in my case I'm going to get dynamic data, it's not a list of objects, but an array of data (strings, integers, dates, etc...)

my question is: is there way to pass a custom list to `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` instead of list of predefined objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to use `JRMapCollectionDataSource` instead of `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`
this way I can pass data like so:

```
List<Map<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
row.put("state", "State value");
row.put("branch", "Branch value");
row.put("productLine", "Product line value");
// add the row to the list
list.add(row);

// and finaly pass the list to datasource
JRDataSource ds = new JRMapCollectionDataSource(list);
```